# QDomDocument and QCryptographicHash issues

Tags: xml, qt, hash

am using `QCryptographicHash` to hash a pass and save it in an XML file, my problem is when I use `QDomDocument` to read and update other elements  in my xml file the element password changes and I don't know how.

any help please !!!

here is my xml file with correct data

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Folders>
 <folder DriveL="" Mounted="false" PassW="!Å?L,-;©Óñn?Ãs?N·¦ø" Path="C:\MyProjects\DiskCrypt\testFolder\TestFolder"/>
```

when I need to update the drive letter I use `QDomDocument` to read data and modify it, every thing goes all right. My application encrypt my xml file if the user exit ant decrypt it once it rerun, but after the decryption I get this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Folders>
 <folder DriveL="" Mounted="false" PassW="!??L,-;???n??s?N???" Path="C:\MyProjects\DiskCrypt\testFolder\TestFolder"/>
</Folders>
```

so `PassW` should be `"!Å?L,-;©Óñn?Ãs?N·¦ø"` but after encryption it is `"!??L,-;???n??s?N???"`, I use simple algorithm for encrption and decryption (AES 128).

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the xml result you expect and the one you get, along with the code you are using to read and write the xml elements.

Comment: Maybe you want to hex-encode the hash in your XML data. If you do not, it will get complicated to ensure the integrity of the hash data, which will be binary if you don't hex-encode it. `QByteArray::toHex()` is your friend.

Comment: thank you gays,I retest my application and the problem was that I missed  `toHex()` like @leemes said, thank you for your time any way.

Comment: @oumaya I've written this as an answer. It'd be kind if you accepted it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid text encoding issues and also make your XML file human-readable, you should never put binary data directly into your XML document. Use base64 or hexadecimal encoding instead.

Since `QCryptographicHash` generates a hash in binary form, you have to call `.toHex()` on the byte array you got from it. (Base64 would also be OK and even smaller, but hexadecimal encoding of hashes is "the default" way to make them human-readable.)